# Aura Enabled Apex Action - param not getting set

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura-enabled

I am using action.setParams, but when I check the params they are not being set.

I'm not getting any error messages, the variable I'm using to populate the parameter is populated, but when I check the params after calling 'set params' it looks like it isn't populated, and in the apex action the param is returning null.

The other params are populating and working in apex code.

Apex Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateAction(Parent__c  updateParent, List<Map<String, String>> existingChild, List<Lead> newChild){
  ...
}
```

Key piece of controller code:

```
let newChildLeadList = [];
newChildArray.forEach(function(element){
   newChildLeadList.push(element.Lead__r);
});
console.log(newChildLeadList);

updateAction.setParams({updateParent: updateParent, existingChild: existingChild, newChild: newChildLeadList});

console.log('get params - ');
         console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updateAction.getParams())));
```

This logs out newChildLeadList populated correctly -

```
[{...}]
0: 
  FirstName: 'aaa'
  LastName: 'aaa'
  etc.
```

But the get params only has the first two params populated (updateParent, existingChild) - the last param (newChild) is not populated at all.

I've tried changing the 'type' of newChild param (in apex code) to List> (same as param that is working) but it still doesn't populate, and then the entire apex action seems to fail (no error message but it doesn't do anything).

**Full Code:**

Component attributes:

```
<aura:attribute name="parent" type="parent__c"/>
<aura:attribute name="newChildFields" type="Map" default="{}"/>
<aura:attribute name="newChildArray" type="child__c[]" default="[]"/>
```

controller.js:

```js
editExisting: function(component, event, helper){

 let updateParent = component.get("v.parent");
 let updateAction = component.get("c.updateAction");
 let existingChild = updateParent.child__r;
 let newChildArray = component.get("v.newChildArray");
 console.log('new child array:');       
 console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newChildArray)));

let newChildLeadList = [];
newChildArray.forEach(function(element){
   newChildLeadList.push(element.Lead__r);
});
console.log(newChildLeadList);
updateAction.setParams({updateParent: updateParent, existingChild: existingChild, newChild: newChildLeadList});

console.log('get params - ');
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updateAction.getParams())));

updateAction.setCallback(this, function(response){
     console.log('action completed');

});
$A.enqueueAction(updateAction);
console.log('action enqueued');
        }       
    },
```

Apex Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateAction(Parent__c  updateParent, List<Map<String, String>> existingChild, List<Lead> newChild){
    System.debug('updateParent');
    System.debug(updateParent);
    System.debug('existingChild');
    System.debug(existingChild);
    System.debug('newChild');
    System.debug(newChild);
}
```

Comment: try using Object[] newChild in apex controller and then change it when you recieve it in apex or pass it as a stirng and deserialize it as sobject.

Comment: I think variable "existingChild" in controller.js stores the list of records of child object [say API Name - child__c]. So, in apex, you can take the records in List<childApiName__c> existingChild parameter.